# Are these chestnuts safe to eat?

Tags: chestnuts

I bought some chestnuts last week. The package date said December 4th and I want to cook them. It's the 5th today. I kept them out on kitchen counter all week. Are they safe to cook and eat still?

If the chestnuts are safe to eat, how long do I keep them in oven to cook them? I have never cooked chestnuts before so I have no way to compare notes to how I cook chestnuts.

Comment: Would you please clarify what kind of chestnuts you bought? Fresh or pre-cooked and sealed?